# What are the list of dependencies for Karate UI Automation

Tags: dependencies, driver, karate

can any of you help me to find out the dependencies for *Karate UI automation (not UI tool) driver dependencies*?
Had found [this](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/intuit/karate/) but no *README* available to find out an exact jar for driver(UI) automation

had tried using *Karate-core* but on the feature file the intelligence is not showing the available methods when I try *driver.*

When *driver.*
Then *driver.*

If i get exact dependency to use, so that the feature file will suggest the available methods to use like:
*driver.location()*
*driver.input[]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate Driver is still experimental, and here is my honest opinion (as the creator) please don't use it yet. It is clear from the questions you are asking that it is a little too much for you to handle in its current form.

That said, there is a README - I am surprised that you say you can't find it - which itself says a lot: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core

If you expect autocomplete "intelligence" then I'm sorry, Karate is not for you.

For the benefit of others who may read this answer - since Karate is a scripting language, you don't have strong typing. The Karate UI makes up for this because it has a powerful debugger: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI - which most teams don't need because of the very strong logging and HTML reporting in dev mode, such as this: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/935029435140489216

Comment: Thank you @Peter for clarifying.